# CodeceptJS / Puppeteer doesn't recognize 'if' statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, codeceptjs

not really familiar with js/node.js. using codeceptjs/puppeteer for some automated tests. right now trying to edit a description in a test. but sometimes a description isn't there - therefor the 'edit description' button is not there - and there is a 'add description' button instead. so I wrote an if statement that specifies . but the code just rolls over it. it does not matter what the statement is, it just moves to the next line. currently `if (desc)` and `if(!desc)` both perform the same function - it goes to the next line in the if statement. this causes an error because there is a description already and therefor the 'add description' button is not available. I'm not sure what's going on.

```
Scenario('test something', (I, userLoginPage, FBPagePage) => {


    userLoginPage.validate();


    I.click('//*[@id="card_611"]');
       // clicks the card

    var desc = '//*[@id="show_card_description"]/section/button';
    // add description button
    // tried 'Add description' but the result was the same

    if (desc){
     // this is where the error happens. it simply looks for the add description button
     // no matter what button is there it decides to click the 'add description' button

        I.click('//*[@id="show_card_description"]/section/button');
    // click add desc button

        I.fillField('//*[@id="description_editor_container"]/div[2]/div[1]',
        'not admin user created this description thanks to automated testing');
    // types this stuff 
        I.click('//*[@id="description_editor_container"]/button[1]');
    // saves it 
        I.wait(1);
}

    I.click('//*[@id="show_card_description"]/section/h5/a');
    // click edit desc button if a description already exists
    I.fillField('//*[@id="description_editor_container"]/div[2]/div[1]', 'not admin user edited this description thanks to automated testing');
    I.click('//*[@id="description_editor_container"]/button[1]');


I.say('success!')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you the right context: You are asking a Node.js question, not CodeceptJS or Puppeteer at first place.

`desc` is always `true` because you declare it as a string, so no matter what the code inside the `if` will run, as you already found out.

You can use do something like:

```js
const numOfElements = await I.grabNumberOfVisibleElements('#show_card_description section button'); // Use CSS locator instead of Xpath for easier readability

console.log(numOfElements); // Debug

if(numOfElements === 1) {
   …
}
```

See also https://codecept.io/helpers/Puppeteer#grabnumberofvisibleelements

Answer (score 0):

The maintainers don't have support for if statement using regular features files in scenario functions citing it as a bad practice for testing due to unexpected results, instead you have to do them inside of custom helper files like this:

```
   /**
   * Checks the specified locator for existance, if it exists, return true
   * If it is not found log a warning and return false.
   */

  async checkElement(locator) 
  {
    let driver = this.helpers["Appium"].browser;
    let elementResult = await driver.$$(locator);
    if (elementResult === undefined || elementResult.length == 0) 
    {
      //console.log("Locator: " + locator + " Not Found");
      return false;
    } 
    else if (elementResult[0].elementId) 
    {
      //console.log("Locator: " + locator + " Found");
      return true;
    }
  }
```

reference - https://codecept.io/helpers/